# One-click reading mode on Firefox Android gone?

Tags: firefox-for-android

When viewing an article page, the address bar used to have a reading mode icon; clicking on it would turn the page to reading node instantly. 
Now I've upgraded it to latest version. I found that if I want to view a page in reading mode I need to:

- click menu icon
- click add to reading list icon
- click on switch icon which appears floating on the page
- it takes me to the reading list, the I need to click on the article I want to read.

So. Question: 
How do I switch a page to reading mode in one click?

Comment: I do not see the issue in my Firefox for Android v41.0. I opened a wiki page, tapped once that reading mode icon in the URL bar and the page opened up in reading mode instantly. Nowhere I had to save it in reading list. See if clearing data from Settings app would help. Or could it be specific to particular articles? I don't know. Can you share the link for any of the article where you encountered the issue?

Comment: @Firelord, thanks for the reply. Yes, I later found out that the issue was happening to some of the websites. For these particular websites, there was "reading mode" icon in address bar in old FF version but not in new version. So, Mozilla probably changed the logic behind when to put the icon in address bar, now I'm wondering what the logic is. I'll Google a while and see if I find anything.

Comment: strange enough. I'm using FF 41.0.1 Windows at the moment, it displays the icon for stackoverflow question page, but not for the page.